# Paramiko issues with SSH login

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I've been working with Paramiko the past few days and so far I love it, I am running into an issue now with trying to ssh into a snmp trap. I believe it's that, because I can run the same script on another server and it works great. Basically the script will get me ssh'd into the server and run a command but hang when it gets to stdout, or stderr lines. I then have to close the terminal window and reopen as it won't let me <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to get out. Has anyone else come across this problem and how did you fix it. Thanks in advance!

**Paramiko Script**

```
import paramiko
import getpass

pw = getpass.getpass()

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect('example.com', username='usernam', password=pw)
paramiko.common.logging.basicConfig(level=paramiko.common.DEBUG)
print "has connection."
transport = client.get_transport()
transport.set_keepalive(1)

stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command("foo")

data = stdout.read()
f = open('/Users/myMac/directory/foo.txt', 'w')
f.write(data)
f.close()

client.close()
```

**My Log**

```
has connection.
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 1] Max packet in: 34816 bytes
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 1] Max packet out: 4096 bytes
INFO:paramiko.transport:Secsh channel 1 opened.
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 1] Sesch channel 1 request ok
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Sending global request "keepalive@example.com"
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Sending global request "keepalive@example.com"
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Sending global request "keepalive@example.com"
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Sending global request "keepalive@example.com"
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Sending global request "keepalive@example.com"
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Sending global request "keepalive@example.com"
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Sending global request "keepalive@example.com"
....
```

And keeps going until I close the terminal.

Comment: I don't see how this question is related to SNMP (or SNMP traps in particular). SNMP traps are a type of network message, that managed equipment can send to a managing system to notify of an occured event.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this behaviour is caused by `transport.set_keepalive(1)` line. It is sending after a 1 second interval a "keepalive" packet. If that is the case, the following link might be helpful : 
 https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/paramiko/paramiko/symbols/python/paramiko/transport/Transport/set_keepalive 

 What do you mean by "script works great on another server" ?

Comment: I agree that it's the keepalive that is creating the neverending list going. If I take that out it just hangs in that same spot. _"What do you mean by "script works great on another server" ?"_ I mean, if I use this script to ssh into another server with a command it works. I think the issue on this is something with snmp. I am now working on using Exscript to see if this will work.